# Is it possible to send Calendar updates to the organiser if the meeting has been moved

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, office365, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

So basically what the issue is, is that we have over 40+ meeting rooms set up in O365 and all are set up to process requests automatically (accept/decline based on availability).

It has been agreed for a team of users to be able to over ride and even kick people out of meetings if an urgent need came up so this has been done by giving them Calendar ownership to all the rooms on Powershell and is working nicely.

My question is this - if the said team move someone from one room to another or change the time of the meeting etc is there a way of automatically notifying the meeting organiser of the change without a separate email coming out from the team informing, because they dont always do it so i wanted to eliminate the 'human element' and see if it was possible for O365 to automatically notify users.

Ta

Comment: Virtually anything is possible, if you know exactly what you want and how to go about it. You are asking to create a watcher for the object you mention then take actions. So, you need to write all that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this issue here. If I give Test1 owner permission on admin’s calendar folder, the admin will receive emails automatically if Test1 change the meeting details.

In the system message, I’ll see “Test1” has forwarded the meeting request. Is this the same as yours?

[image]

This occurs if I select to send updates to all attendee. If I select to only send updates to added or deleted attendees, admin will not see this message.